# iOS - How to reset that an application has requested access to the reminder database

Tags: ios, ios7

My iOS application accesses the reminder database on the device.  After running the app from Xcode and accessing the reminder database from the app, the Settings / Privacy setting for Reminders correctly lists the app as having requested access to the reminder database.  When I uninstall the app, the Settings / Privacy setting for Reminders no longer lists the app as having requested access to the reminder database.  All of that is the behavior I would expect.  The problem is, when I rerun the app from Xcode, the app shows up in the Settings / Privacy setting for Reminders as having requested access to the reminder database, even though the new installation of the app has not requested access to the reminder database yet.  The fact that an earlier installation of the app accessed the reminder database is being cached somewhere.  My question is: how can I reset the Settings / Privacy setting for Reminders so it forgets that an earlier installation of the app had accessed the reminder database?  Uninstalling the app does not seem to be enough to do that.  This problem prevents repeatable testing of first-time access to the reminder database.  The behavior is the same for the calendar database.

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to [resetting the push notifications permissions alert](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42), Apple says:

> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> - Delete your app from the device.
> - Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> - Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
> - Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

You can try that and see if it works with the reminders alert as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @rmaddy: I wouldn't say nothing. It may not be the right answer, but it's related because a system provided alert regarding an app's permission to do something showed once and no more after that, even after uninstalling the app. That applies to both push notifications and reminders (and apparently other privacy settings), so to say that it has nothing to do with the question is a stretch.